# Decide between Polyglossia and Babel for LuaLaTeX in 2019

Tags: luatex, babel, polyglossia, incompatibility, comparison

Which are the key questions one has to ask to **decide between Polyglossia and Babel for a LuaLaTeX project in 2019**?

There has been a similar, more general [question in 2012](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88481/polyglossia-vs-babel), but the packages have changed a lot in the meantime. Hence I open a new, more specific question.

Can we reduce it to a check list like

**Use package A, if you need**

- utf-8 characters
- right to left support

**Use package B, if you need**

- package foo, because A breaks foo

Comment: Would you be OK with expanding the question to XeLaTeX as well, so this question is truly a more modern version of the other one or do you think it would be more useful to have a separate XeLaTeX question (I don't know if there are relevant differences between the two, but I think `babel`'s new RTL support works better for LuaLaTeX than XeLaTeX, though I could be completely wrong.)

Comment: For packages like `csquotes` and `biblatex`, but also some others like https://ctan.org/pkg/tracklang and packages using it `polyglossia` has the disadvantage that it does not expose language variants in a way that can be picked up easily by those packages. That means that there are some rough edges with dialect forms (`english`, `british`, `american`; `ngerman`, `german`, `naustrian`, ...). See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432347/35864. Most of those packages won't exactly break with `polyglossia`, but they work better/smoother with `babel`.

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to use `polyglossia` over `babel` for `lualatex`.

Comment: @JonasStein why would you think that? There are still many scripts that luatex does not support.

Comment: I’ve frequently tried to answer questions and write MCVEs about languages that `babel` supports and `polyglossia` doesn’t. Sorry if that’s an obvious point.

Comment: On the other hand, some language files for `babel` still use obsolete encodings by default in a way that requires workarounds for a LuaLaTeX source file in UTF-8, and the `\babelfont` mechanism is somewhat kludgy; I’ve found, for example, that it disables `Ligatures=TeX`.

Comment: @Davislor  It's even worse -- `\defaultfontfeatures` is ignored altogether. This is a bug, already fixed on the repository. I'll upload the new version to CTAN very likely tomorrow.

Comment: @JavierBezos That explains the problems I was having with `Scale`.

Comment: @Davislor Yes. I commited the fix 12 days ago. See https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/5c8c78416908c06dac7457ba7e324733c28c867b#diff-7f361ed9d5b1603be6a4176a34e39a08 .

Comment: @JonasStein You can find some notes on the scripts supported by luatex on https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/wiki/Babel:-Remarks-on-the-luatex-support-for-some-scripts .

Comment: @moewe Thank you for your suggestion. The situation for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX is not 100% the same. I have created the pendant for XeLaTeX too. So we have a more specific, less broad question and it fits better to the sx scheme. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482611/decide-between-polyglossia-and-babel-for-xelatex-in-2019

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here's some reasons why I prefer `babel` over `polyglossia` for LuaLaTeX.

- `babel`'s base is part of the LaTeX core packages actively developed, but `polyglossia` is only getting a few minor updates.
- `babel`'s RTL and BiDi support is really nice for LuaLaTeX now. But `polyglossia` only supports RTL text with XeLaTeX.
- `babel`'s new `ini` system for setting up languages is very neat and I think will improve rapidly. It also makes it easy to add new languages and update existing languages.
- `babel`'s font support is easier to use to set up standard families for different languages, whereas `polyglossia` basically just uses standard `fontspec` calls.
- For standard European languages `babel`'s support is very mature.
- `polyglossia`'s language variants do not work well with `biblatex` or `csquotes`.

You might choose `polyglossia` if you want to write a RTL only document with XeLaTeX, as the `bidi` package has been around for a long time. But if the main document language is LTR, I wouldn't do this now as `babel` and LuaLaTeX is better and involves less hacks and workarounds. You might also choose to use `polyglossia` with XeLaTeX if you need certain complex scripts that LuaLaTeX still does not handle well. But none of these reasons justify choosing `polyglossia` over `babel` if you have already decided to use LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Just for the records, most of the issues here are no longer true: polyglossia is actively developed again; polyglossia does support RTL with LuaTeX; the only remaining LuaTeX issues are due to LuaTeX restrictions wrt font rendering; polyglossia has easy support to setup fonts for different languages/script; as of 1.45, polyglossia has an extended language interface that lets other packages access variants in all detail (will be used by biblatex 3.14 and csquotes 5.2f).

Comment: I doubt there are less hacks in `babel` since `polyglossia` is the newer code and it claims to be more modern.

Comment: @tanGIS, I'm referring to the bidi package. TeX does not do RTL well. Babel uses Lua code for RTL things.

Comment: @DavidPurton you should rewrite your answer. It's not clear that you refer to bidi regarding hacks. Besides there is `luabidi` which makes it possible to use RTL with `polyglossia` also under LuaHBTeX or LuaLaTeX. I do find it unfair to claim polyglossia is not actively developed when there are several updates a year.

Comment: @tanGIS, at the time this answer was written there were no updates to polyglossia and luabidi was next to useless. LuaHBTex was not released. JSpittzm has already noted in the comments that most of these objections are no longer true. Since I have not had time to carefully investigate things now for myself I have not updated the answer. Perhaps the best option is for you to add a new answer that better reflects the current state of things.

Answer (score 24):

There are 79 language definition files (gloss-XX) in the `polyglossia` folder. For a thorough comparison you would have to compare for every language how good the gloss-file is, if it works with lualatex, if `babel` provides definitions for this language too and how good it works with lualatex. And naturally you also need to check if babel knows a language which `polyglossia` doesn't have. That's a lot of work which I won't do (but it is known that the French module is clearly better in babel).

For all languages relevant to me I prefer today `babel` over `polyglossia`. Even more so if I use lualatex as babel has more lualatex specific code (`polyglossia`) has been developed with xelatex in mind).

`babel` is better maintained and its interface for other packages which need language support (`biblatex`) is better.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I am not able to provide a holistic answer to the question. But I know `polyglossia` does the job for me. Since end of 2019 it is also quite active again. There is one point where `polyglossia` beats `babel`:

1. `polyglossia` provides long-s (ſ) captions with the option `blackletter`.

*Edit*: There used to be a second point about language metadata which is resolved as of `hyperxmp` 5.4. Thumbs up for Scott and Javier for resolving this quickly.

Comment: Thanks for adding this!

Comment: `babel` does provide BCP 47 tags (about 250): https://github.com/latex3/babel/wiki/What's-new-in-babel-3.43 . And long-s is certainly possible with `babel`.

Comment: @JavierBezos the BCP47 codes cannot be used by `hyperxmp` today and there is no blackletter option in babel, isn't it?

Comment: There in no option, indeed, but as to `hyperxmp` what you are saying now (after an edit) is not what you said originally in the post. `babel` does provide BCP 47 tags to other packages. If other packages are not using that information is not a limitation in `babel`.

Comment: From my point of view I did not change the meaning with my edit but we are both no native English speakers. I am willing to learn: How does babel return the BCP47 code if I chose the language with `\usepackage[german]{babel}?`

Comment: `\documentclass{article}  \usepackage[german]{babel} 
 \BabelEnsureInfo  \begin{document} \localeinfo{tag.bcp47} 
 \end{document}`. See page 34 in the manual for other keys (which have been in the `ini` files bundled with `babel` for several years).

Comment: Thanks! I sent a link to this question to Scott Pakin from hyperxmp. I am positive he will implement support for babel as well if feasible.

Comment: I willing to help Scott, if he wants.