# Polyglossia pesky about spaces in front of punctuation (French - Lualatex)

Tags: luatex, polyglossia, frenchspacing

I just installed a fresh version of  Basic TeX (version 2019) for Mac
after deleting all previous version of TeXLive.
Documents which used to compile perfectly now fail due to what seems a very pesky behavior of polyglossia about spaces in front of punctuation.

Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
C'est un test : hello
\end{document}
```

fails to compile with warning :

```
warning  (node filter): error: ...ic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polygloss
ia-frpt.lua:166: attempt to call a nil value (upvalue 'remove_node')
```

If I remove the space in front of ":" as in

```
test: hello
```

then all is fine and the correct space in front of ":" is correctly inserted by polyglossia.

This is more than irritating. There were errors of this type in the past but they had been fixed. Why is it back and how to avoid these spurious warnings ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not having that problem at all. I do have the full TeX Live 2019 installed by MacTeX and with all updates. First, have you tried to update your BasicTeX using either tlmgr or TeX Live Utility? If it's already fully updated are you sure you don't have an older version of a package in your personal tree that's interfering with the one in BasicTeX? Please publish the log file.

Comment: I wouldn't use polyglossia for French. The babel module is imho better.

Comment: I can reproduce the error and also see the cause: the lua tries to access a field in a table which is no longer there. But I don't know why @HerbSchulz don't get the error, other mac users could reproduce it too.

Comment: Sorry about that... It all works when typeset via xelatex but DOES fail as described when using lualatex. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Possibly relevant [Decide between Polyglossia and Babel for LuaLaTeX in 2019](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482396/35864)

Comment: Bugs like this should be reported to the `polyglossia` maintainer, even though at the moment development seems to be largely dormant. https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/222 seems to be pretty much this bug.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer :   babel with lualatex seems to be the answer to my problem.  moewe links implies the same so I will just revert to using babel. Thanks