# Caption Spacing Wrong do to Polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia, lthooks

Consider the following example:

```
% lualatex test.tex

\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \includegraphics[width = 0.99\textwidth]{example-image-a}
 \caption{Test caption.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{example-image-a}
 \caption{Test caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

As can be seen in the output, the space between the second picture and the corresponding caption is too wide. However, if I remove the [`polyglossia`](https://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) package, the spacing is correct.

What on Earth is going on and how do I fix it?

Note: I think that this is a somewhat new thing (but I'm not sure); I can't remember ever seeing this before.

**Update**

A version of the package with a bugfix has now been released; see [here](https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.3866.1676200360.3715.ctan-ann@ctan.org).

Comment: Not an explanation of the problem, but if you can, I would switch to babel. Babel is much more actively maintained while polyglossia  seems to be crumbling to pieces...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Where can I check this statement about Polyglossia? Since Polyglossia's development resumed a few years ago, it seemed to run fine and I haven't run into any problem (within my use case of course).

Comment: @Miyase See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482396/36296

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz This link is a bit old, and one answer specifies that things have changed since then. Also, the link only points out some lack of features (none of which would impact my usecase anyway), but doesn't say anything about development problems. So I'm still wondering where I could see anything factual indicating that Polyglossia is "crumbling to pieces".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add `\ShowHook{cmd/caption/before}`  you will see `polyglossia` has injected code into the start of `\caption`.

```
-> The generic hook 'cmd/caption/before':
> Code chunks:
>     polyglossia -> \addtocontents {lof}{\protect \setforeignlanguage {\langua
gename }}\addtocontents {lot}{\protect \setforeignlanguage {\languagename }}
```

Leaving a blank line before `\caption` would work around the bug, but it should be reported to `polyglossia` maintainers.

or patching via the hook:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\AddToHook{cmd/caption/before}[polyglossia]{\par}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

%\ShowHook{cmd/caption/before}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \includegraphics[width = 0.99\textwidth]{example-image-a}
 \caption{Test caption.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{example-image-a}
 \caption{Test caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, David. For some reason I can't log into my Github accout at the moment; can I make you report the "bug"?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg as it's Christmas:-)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/575

Comment: I just observed that there is another issue: There is a small white space to the right of the picture, so I have to put a `%` at the end of the line with `\includegraphics` in order ot get the correct centering. (This is independant of the width of the picture.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg that is exactly the issue, you get  space, in the second example a linebreak happens at the space so you get a whole extra line

Comment: Ohhh! I see. `:-)` Thanks for clarifying that for me.

Comment: Do you have any idea when the fix will be released?

Comment: no also it's not entirely unlikely the maintainers are having a break this week @SvendTveskæg